# Mysql UPDATE WIth Multiple Where statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made a script that auto creates Update statement using For loops and all and the final result executes this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table2 
              SET(code2='sfvv' WHERE number='1'),
                 (code2='sdvsdv' WHERE number='2') 
              WHERE id='32'") or die ( mysql_error() );
```

The error said:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(code2='sfvv' WHERE number='1'),(code2='sdvsdv' WHERE number='2') WHERE i' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need `case statement`

```
UPDATE table2 
SET code2= case number when 1 then 'sfvv' when 2 then 'sdvsdv' END
where id = 32
```

Comment: It worked for my case I finally got it working , thankyou , I learned something new :)

Answer (score 2):

You use `AND` and `OR` statements to combine conditions:

```
UPDATE table2
SET code2 = 'sfvv'
WHERE
    (number = '1'AND code2 = 'sdvsdv')
    OR
    (number = '2' AND id = '32')
```

You can update multiple values in the same row by using commas to separate the statements:

```
UPDATE table2
SET code2 = 'sfvv', code3 = 'abc'
```

If you need to update different rows based on different conditions, you need to execute multiple queries:

```
UPDATE table2 SET code2 = 'sfvv' WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE table2 SET code3 = 'abc' WHERE id = 2;
```

As the other answer mentioned, you can also use case statements in your `SET` clause:

```
UPDATE table2
SET code2 = CASE WHEN number = 1 THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END
```

But this is not 100% flexible. Use it when it makes sense.

Comment: _You use AND and OR statements to combine conditions:_ Possibly you should use an `OR` in your first sql statement as currently that wont do anything unless `number` can be 1 AND 2 at the same time???

Comment: Number 1 and 2 are different rows and they are 1,2 they are updated to the given code2 which both are null

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, was too focused on formatting the code.

Comment: ThankYou Both For Trying It Reminded me that I can still use OR & AND in situations like these ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
Update  table2 
     SET code2= CASE 
                 WHEN  number=1 THEN 'sfvv'
                 WHEN  number=2 THEN 'sdvsdv'
                 ELSE  code2
                 END 
     WHERE id = 32
```

Hope it helps